# How to send SOAP request and receive response using Flex Mobile?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, soap, soap-client

I am newbie to flex mobile applications, need to send a soap request to a web service using my flex mobile application, does anyone know of any tutorial or sample ? What I have found so far are related to flex application not mobile applications.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WebService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_3.html) tag.  Documentation on it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've already studied it, it seems its for Flex applications not Mobile applications, I am looking for a simple Mobile application. Please correct me if I am wrong, Thanks.

Comment: Flex can be used to build mobile applications.  You tagged your question with Flex; and put "Flex Mobile" in your subject line.  Are you using Flex?  If so, then I stand by my answer.  Using the WebService tag is no different in a mobile application than it is in a browser based application.  If you are not using Flex; you'll have to provide more details.

Comment: Yes I am developing Flex Mobile application using FlashBuilder. Do you know of any helloword the example of the provided link is a bit complex and I cant run it on my system.

Comment: Google is your friend. Second result for "flex soap webservice." http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_3.html I used that page about two months ago to build a service package and it definitely helped.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 That is the same page I linked to in my original answer.  I'm not sure how to provide a simpler explanation for Eme.

Comment: Woops. Sorry. I had two tabs open, the Livedocs page and the page we linked to. I had assumed I opened the livedocs page via your link. My mistake, Flextras.